# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: No deserializer defined

Tags: hadoop, jasper-reports, hbase, ireport

I am tring to connect HBASE with `jasperreports-server-cp-6.0.1`. I have `hadoop 2.5.2` and `hbase-1.0.1` installed on my system.

I have installed `HBasePlugin-0.5.1.nbm` plugin in `iReport 5.6.0`.

I have followed all the steps given in:  http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/hadoop-hbase

When I write the following Query:

```
{ "tableName" : "blogposts",   "deserializerClass" : "com.jaspersoft.hbase.deserialize.impl.ShellDeserializer" }
```

In iReport, I am getting the following error:

```
Message:
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: No deserializer defined
Level:
    SEVERE
Stack Trace:
No deserializer defined
    com.jaspersoft.hadoop.hbase.query.HBaseQueryWrapper.<init>(HBaseQueryWrapper.java:152)
    com.jaspersoft.hadoop.hbase.HBaseFieldsProvider.getFields(HBaseFieldsProvider.java:50)
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.hbase.designer.HBaseFieldsProvider.getFields(HBaseFieldsProvider.java:57)
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.hbase.connection.HBaseConnection.readFields(HBaseConnection.java:185)
    com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.wizards.ConnectionSelectionWizardPanel.validate(ConnectionSelectionWizardPanel.java:146)
    org.openide.WizardDescriptor$7.run(WizardDescriptor.java:1357)
    org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)
    org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)
```

Could you please help me with this error (I also tried with `iReport 4.0.2`, but I received the same error)?

Answer (score 0):

Both iReport and the HBase connector are outdated.
Try using the Apache Phoenix JDBC driver which is compatible with the latest release (6.2) of the Jaspersoft products:

http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/how-use-apache-phoenix-jdbc-driver-run-reports-hbase

Thanks!